# Typescript: Date operations From Javascript to typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm passing a code from Javascript to TypeScript, but I have a problem in a code, where I do an operation with Dates:

```
function(d) {
    let di = new Date(d);
    let df = new Date(d);
    df.setMonth(d.getMonth() + 1);
    let dl = +new Date(+new Date(df) - +new Date(di)) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
    return (dl * cellSize) - 45;
};
```

The d variable is a Date object with value 2016-08-31, the problem is the operations in dl: it throws an error:

> Argument of type 'Date' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.

I have searched on google and StackOverflow, and the only thing I found it was to add a + before *new* keyword. Is there any other or better way ? Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`di` and `df` are already dates. You're trying to use them as argument to `Date`, i.e. `new Date(new Date)`. That's a) rather nonsensical and b) where your error comes from (`new Date` accepts an integer or string as argument, not a `Date`).

Get rid of the `new Date()` around `df` and `di`.

Comment: You may get another error trying to treat `Date` objects as `Number`; use `di.getTime()` instead of `+di`…